# Why does my new subsectioning heading not gobble the subsection title?

Tags: macros, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I hope I'm not missing anything obvious. Instead of trying to elaborate on my title, let me illustrate with an MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{%
\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
              {2ex \@plus .2ex}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section}    
\subsection{Sub-}
\subsubsection{Subsub-}
\subsubsubsection{subsubsub-}

\end{document}
```

***Result:***

[image: My \subsubsubsection command is not consuming its argument]

***Remarks:***

1. The problem goes away if I use `\subsubsubsection*`, but still exists if I use `\subsubsubsection` without changing `secnumdepth`.
2. Yes, I'm aware of the `\paragraph` command: I don't want to use it because what I'm using `\subsubsubsection` for are not paragraphs. If you would like to suggest some other less repetitive name, I'm open to suggestions.

What's going on here?

Comment: `\newcommand\subsubsubsectionmark[1]{}` is missing.

Comment: @Ulrike: the missing `\subsubsubsectionmark` was exactly the problem: please turn that into an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\newcommand\subsubsubsectionmark[1]{}` is missing: Sectioning commands defined with `\@startsection` executes such a mark command internally with the title as argument and you must define it so that it grabs the title as argument. (You don't get an error if the definition is missing as `\csname...\endcsname` is used).